# Linq to Xml Grouping by tag

Tags: xml, tags, linq-to-xml

I have a xml similar to this one:

```
<data>
<date>24/11</date>
<info>Info I want to get</info>
<info>Info I want to get</info>
<info>Info I want to get</info>

<date>25/11</date>
<info>Info I want to get</info>
<info>Info I want to get</info>
<info>Info I want to get</info>
</data>
```

The thing is, Im able to get all the info tags, but I get the results from all dates.


I dont know what the dates will be, since the are dynamic generated. What I know is that I may have a data tag with one or two date tags


I wish I could show the first date´s info on a list box and the second date´s info on another listbox. How can I do that?


Desirable Output:

```
textbox with the first date

value of tag info related to the first date
value of tag info related to the first date
value of tag info related to the first date
```

If there´s a second date then print it too:

```
textbox with the second date

value of tag info related to the second date
value of tag info related to the second date
value of tag info related to the second date
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of ListBox (e.g. Windows Forms, ASP.NET, WPF) you want to populate so I simply show you how to group that XML input:

```
    XDocument input = XDocument.Load("../../XMLFile4.xml");
    var groups =
        from info in input.Root.Elements("info")
        group info by info.ElementsBeforeSelf("date").Last() into g
        select new
        {
            date = (string)g.Key,
            infos = (from infoEl in g select (string)infoEl).ToList()
        };

    foreach (var item in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", item.date);
        foreach (string info in item.infos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", info);
        }
    }
```

Output then is e.g.

```
Date: 24/11
        Info I want to get
        Info I want to get
        Info I want to get
Date: 25/11
        Info I want to get
        Info I want to get
        Info I want to get
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that its a windows phone app. I will try this!

Comment: Well, its was not what I really needed but, the method ElementsBeforeSelf game a ideia so I could do some filtering here. The real xml data was a little more complicated than that. Thx!